# how to search the string like google search php

Tags: php, search, full-text-search

i want to know how to get search like google search...

thanks and advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google's search engine inside of your website.

If you want to have your own PHP and MySQL search you can try Sphider that is found on: http://www.sphider.eu/